# simple form association as hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm trying to pass association values as hidden field in simple form

so same functionality like when you do ...

```
= simple form for @document do |f|
 = f.association :clients
```

...but will generate hidden field insted

I'm trying to do it as this

```
  = f.association :clients, as: hidden
```

but that wont work obviously

only thing that works for me is

```
%input{ name: 'document[client_ids][]', value: '1'}
%input{ name: 'document[client_ids][]', value: '2'}
%input{ name: 'document[client_ids][]', value: '3'}
```

Comment: have you tried  `= f.association :clients, type: 'hidden'` ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
=f.hidden_field :client_id, :value => "some value"
```

but I think you'd be better of explaining the bigger picture and then we can suggest a suitable rails answer for you.  In most cases using hidden fields is a sign that something should be done a better way.

Answer (score 1):

An array is sent on submit from associations in simple form.
The following will allow for this using a hidden field:

```
  <%= f.hidden_field('client_ids][', value: "some value") %>
```

(Note: The reversed brackets are important)

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
<%= f.association :clients, input_html: { hidden: true } %>
```

should work.

Comment: no this wont work for 2 reasons, Simple form f.association is excepting first parameter association field symbol, (e.g. :clients for has_many :clients) and even if I generate these fields, they are still  select html tag with just hidden=hidden argument

Comment: what's wrong with hidden="hidden"? http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute